# PHP how to implement an async timeout operation?

Tags: php, multithreading, timer, timeout, timertask

I have a web application in LAMP environment.

I have some ajax call to handle with an async timeout callback, the flow would be:

1. Ajax call from client
2. Server (php/apache) replies to client and open a timer (let's say 15 minutes, the timing will be variable)
3. The client receives the ajax response immediately
4. The timer keeps running server side
5. At timer timeout a callback is processed server side (the client doesn't know it)

I don't know how to handle this kind of request with PHP.
The only way I can image is to store in a database the timeout time and build a polling process (with cron and curl local call) that checks if there are some records in the database to be processed with a query.
With this olution the precision of the timeout operation would be very poor, at last one minute and honestily I don't like the polling approach.

With a different technology, let's say Java, I would open a separate thread with the timer... how to do it in a php script page?

Comment: you can use queue with using redi or db, if you're using laravel then you can look this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues and also with task scheduling https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling, if you're using plain php you can use this lib https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is quite hard to do elegantly in PHP, my approach would be to use the exec function:

```
 exec("php callback.php  > /dev/null &");
```

That will create a new process and with the output redirection you do not have to wait for the process to finish. It depends on what kind of throughput you need to achieve and how reliable this timer function needs to be.

Comment: and the timer will be handled by callpack.php page with a sleep?

Comment: Yes, you can pass the number of seconds/minutes/hours as an argument to the callback script. That way you can pass data from the main process to this separate one.